# How to add border line using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a border to a widget which is working but it is not capturing the overall the wigets fields only half part is drawing a line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfiS2.png)

HTML:

```
    <p class="solid">
   <img src="log.jpg" width="20" height="20"/>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="c.data.message" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" ng-click="c.add()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>

 </p>
```

CSS:

```
p.solid {border-style: solid;}
```

Comment: You can not nest `div` into `p`, that is invalid HTML. The error correction of the browser is fixing your mistake, by closing the `p` element as soon as it encounters the starting tag of the `div`.

Comment: are you closing <p class="solid"> tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A paragraph is not intended as a wrapper for other block elements. The rendering engine will automatically close the `<p>` tag before opening the `<div>` that follows, therefore rendering an empty paragraph with no height, resulting in just a border without anything else. Change the paragraph to a `<div>` (or any other semantically feasible element) and it will work.

```css
.solid {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="solid">

  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" ng-model="c.data.message" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="c.add()" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Constantin. One quick question why we use .solid in css ? what . refres to ?

Comment: `.` is the class selector. When you add `class="solid"` you can select it in CSS via `.solid`, just like you can use `id="something"` via `#something`. I'd suggest you find a beginner's tutorial for CSS that explains the very basics. :-)

Comment: If your question refers to why it was decided to use that notation - I don't know either. Maybe there's an explanation you can find on the web, otherwise you'd have to ask the inventors of CSS why they decided to use the dot and hash. ;)